# Scrolling up a button when another button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a Online Question based system. In this I got three button at the top of the page. There are 100 buttons in the side div height of 200px with auto scrollbar. My problem is when I click the first button in the top, the button under the scrollbar in the div should scroll up and display. Can u please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to animate the scrolling of the div and not the position of the button:

```
$("#yourdiv").animate({ scrollTop: "200px"}, 500);
```

Where 200px is the height you want to scroll down, and 500 is the time in ms of the animation